# Need to use stringr to parse text based on location of string

Tags: r, stringr

I have the following data set. I used `devtools::reproduce()` to put a sample of my data in here and I only selected the column I need help with, which is `genres`.

There are a lot of genres listed below. I am working with a movie database and I want to simply use only the first genre listed in there (in this format: `Genre1 | Genre2 | Genre3`).

How do I use `stringr` or another package to parse this string data in the way I want?

The end result is to use it in a regression model.

```
> dput(droplevels(head(movie.cpi,4)))
structure(list(num_critic_for_reviews = c(723L, 302L, 813L, 462L
), director_facebook_likes = c(0L, 563L, 22000L, 475L), actor_3_facebook_likes = c(855L, 
1000L, 23000L, 530L), actor_1_facebook_likes = c(1000L, 40000L, 
27000L, 640L), gross = c(866161204.765035, 364628240.876025, 
476821933.103659, 77736216.375), genres = structure(c(2L, 1L, 
4L, 3L), .Label = c("Action|Adventure|Fantasy", "Action|Adventure|Fantasy|Sci-Fi", 
"Action|Adventure|Sci-Fi", "Action|Thriller"), class = "factor"), 
    num_voted_users = c(886204L, 471220L, 1144337L, 212204L), 
    cast_total_facebook_likes = c(4834L, 48350L, 106759L, 1873L
    ), facenumber_in_poster = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), num_user_for_reviews = c(3054L, 
    1238L, 2701L, 738L), content_rating = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L), .Label = "PG-13", class = "factor"), budget = c(269925874.125874, 
    353545586.107091, 266006097.560976, 280583231.707317), title_year = c(2009L, 
    2007L, 2012L, 2012L), actor_2_facebook_likes = c(936L, 5000L, 
    23000L, 632L), imdb_score = c(7.9, 7.1, 8.5, 6.6), movie_facebook_likes = c(33000L, 
    0L, 164000L, 24000L)), .Names = c("num_critic_for_reviews", 
"director_facebook_likes", "actor_3_facebook_likes", "actor_1_facebook_likes", 
"gross", "genres", "num_voted_users", "cast_total_facebook_likes", 
"facenumber_in_poster", "num_user_for_reviews", "content_rating", 
"budget", "title_year", "actor_2_facebook_likes", "imdb_score", 
"movie_facebook_likes"), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: This would probably work `movie.cpi$genre_1 <- gsub( "\\|.*$", "", movie.cpi$genres )`. When you post the complete data, we may say for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the following command you can get the first genre extracted out of that column (I stored it in a new column called `genre_1`):

```
movie.cpi$genre_1 <- gsub( "\\|.*$", "", movie.cpi$genres)

movie.cpi[,c("genres", "genre_1")]

##                            genres genre_1
## 1 Action|Adventure|Fantasy|Sci-Fi  Action
## 2        Action|Adventure|Fantasy  Action
## 3                 Action|Thriller  Action
## 4         Action|Adventure|Sci-Fi  Action
```